# Hover menu not working properly for submenus

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, submenu

I have a simple vertical hover menu and even when I don't hover over any buttons but the cursor is a little to the right of it, it shows the submenu. When there isn't a submenu the main menu button starts to flicker. I am not entirely sure what is going on and why it is happening. Here is [link](http://postimg.org/image/6ibd9ghgz/) to show what I mean.

EDIT: Thank you for your responses! Now I'm having a different/almost same problem. The menu doesn't freak out any more, but now there's a bar that sticks out of it and it is still opening the submenus without having to hover over the parent menu. Link to picture [here](http://postimg.org/image/ebb16g3jf/).

Here's my HTML

```
    <div id="divMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home2</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homef</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homeg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homeh</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homei</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home5</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homej</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homek</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homel</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home6</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
```

And my CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

#divMenu {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#divMenu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#divMenu li {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}

#divMenu li li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#divMenu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 27px;
}

#divMenu ul {
    line-height: 25px;
}

#divMenu li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
}

    #divMenu li li {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        background: #000;
        left: 95px;
        top: -30px;
    }


#divMenu ul li a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Quicksand Light;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px;
}

#divMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 27px;
}

#divMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

#divMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#divMenu ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

#divMenu a:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width:0px` from `#divMenu ul li:hover > a`  and  `#divMenu a:hover` from your style.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the block tripping is because of the width in the block underneath:

```
#divMenu ul li a {
width: 150px;
height: 25px;
padding: 5px 5px;
display: inline-block;
letter-spacing: 6px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
font-family: Quicksand Light;
color: #ffffff;
border: 0px;
}
```

Just remove that width and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

It's due to the zero width you're applying to the links. You really don't need that.

```
#divMenu ul li:hover > a {
    /*width: 0px;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

#divMenu a:hover {
    /*width: 0px;*/
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
```

```css
#divMenu {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#divMenu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#divMenu li {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}

#divMenu li li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#divMenu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 27px;
}

#divMenu ul {
    line-height: 25px;
}

#divMenu li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
}

    #divMenu li li {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        background: #000;
        left: 95px;
        top: -30px;
    }


#divMenu ul li a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Quicksand Light;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px;
}

#divMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 27px;
}

#divMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

#divMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#divMenu ul li:hover > a {
    /*width: 0px;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

#divMenu a:hover {
    /*width: 0px;*/
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home2</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homef</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homeg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homeh</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homei</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home5</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Homej</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homek</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homel</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home6</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
```